# How to avoid race conditions when subscribing to observables in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, race-condition, angular2-observables

I'm new to Angular and was writing this code.

```
  onUpdate(relation: RelationTypes) {
    let userId: number;
    this.assigneeId$.subscribe(assigneeId => userId = assigneeId);

    let customerId: string;
    this.customer$.subscribe(customer => customerId = customer.email);

    this.store.dispatch(actions.changeUserRelation({
      payload: {
        'userId': userId,
        'customerId': customerId,
        'relation': relation
      }
    }));
  }
```

The `customerId$` and `assigneeId$` are observables. I know that there might be the chance of a race condition here, which I would love to eliminate.

So I was thinking of something like this.

```
     this.subscription.add(this.assigneeId$.subscribe(assigneeId => {
       this.customer$.subscribe(customer => {
         this.store.dispatch(actions.changeUserRelation({
           payload: {
             'userId': assigneeId,
             'customerId': customer.email,
             'relation': relation
           }
         }));
       });
     }));
```

But this isn't working. Maybe I you can help me understand and fix the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Part of it is you aren't thinking in observables yet, you don't want to assign a local value (userId, customerId from your code) to the values from the observable, use the values within the subscribe, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74394167/264607

Answer (score 5):

RxJS offer different operators to combine observables. I think in this case you can use `combineLatest`, like this:

```
combineLatest([this.assigneeId$, this.customer$]).subscribe(([assigneeId, customer]) => 
    this.store.dispatch(actions.changeUserRelation({
       payload: {
         'userId': assigneeId,
         'customerId': customer.email,
         'relation': relation
       }
    }));
);
```